# Add Guava to new Maven IntelliJ module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, guava

I'm having trouble adding Google Guava to my IntelliJ project.  I've tried the following:

1. From `pom.xml`, using <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>INSERT</kbd> and selecting "Dependency".  I tried searching for "google", "guava", and "google-guava".  There were no results for any of these searches.
2. The [guava website](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild#Maven) suggests that guava can be found in "Maven Central."  I think that is `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`.  I tried adding that URL to the list at Project Settings->Maven->Repositories.  If I add it to the "Artifactory or Nexus Service URLs" list, when I click "Test" I get the message "No repositories found."  I cannot find a way to add the URL to the list of "Indexed Maven Repositories" (which only has an "Update" button).
3. I tried adding this `<dependency>` snippet directly to `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
       <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
       <version>10.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   but `com.google.guava` gets highlighted in red with a tooltip saying that dependency cannot be found.

How can I get IntelliJ to add Guava as a maven dependency for my project (without downloading it myself)?

### Edit

The Maven Repositories that IntelliJ is already configured with are:

- http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/
- http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/api/
- http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/

The only entry in my "Indexed Maven Repositories" is a local directory:

- /home/benw/.m2/repository

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

this is what is working for me without any special configuration for IntelliJ with `auto-import` turned on for all my Maven projects. Without auto-import you have to tell IntelliJ to manually resolve the `pom.xml` changes.

Make sure you are not overriding the defaults in the `pom.xml` or the `~/.m2/settings.xml` with a mirrors or other incorrect repository declarations.

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>INSERT</kbd> works with dependecies you already have in local repository.
2. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 can not be browsed, but correct link to artifacts works. E.g. try [guava 10.0.1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/)
3. After adding dependency snippet you should reimport Maven project.
   For exmaple your snippet

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
>     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
>     <version>10.0.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

works for me successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Maven itself (by default) pulls from Maven Central automatically if it does not already have a particular artifact in the local repository. So all you should need to do is ensure that IDEA is pointing to "/home/benw/.m2/repository" as your local repository and that there aren't any changes in "/home/benw/.m2/settings.xml" that would be preventing Maven from accessing Central.